# Hbase Java API - createTable Method works, but doesnt finish

Tags: java, api, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am currently trying to use the Java API to connect to hbase and create a new table. It does seem to work, but the admin.createTable() Method does not finish. So "Done!" is never printed, and the programm never ends. Please see the code below.

```
        Configuration config = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
        config.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientport", "2181");

        String tableName = "actors";
        Connection connection;
        try {
            connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(config);
            Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
            Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
            HTableDescriptor htable = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(tableName)); 
            htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("movies"));
            System.out.println( "Creating Table..." );
            admin.createTable( htable );
            System.out.println("Done!");
            table.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

No exception is thrown. If I open a hbase shell, the table actors with column family movies was created. I am running out of ideas here of what I could be doing wrong.

Comment: One possibility is that you may have access to some, but not all region servers. If your logs aren't detailed enough (which probably by default they aren't) you might not be seeing these errors. So maybe your client can access the Master, but not all RS? Just something to triple-check...

Comment: How would I fix this if that was the case?

Comment: That could be anybody's guess. My best guess would be host name resolution? Try accessing all your RS via telnet on the right port from your client machine. If that works then the issue is somewhere else. If it doesn't that's what you have to fix first. Always try to communicate with HBase via host names, not IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

To Identify the exact cause do the following.

- Enable debug logs in log4j.properties where this program is running.
- Include this line inside your try block

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.checkHBaseAvailable(conf);

This will identify if there is any preliminary issues connecting to hbase and throw errors if any.